# How to add two List in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list

This is a question from an interview book. I'm using Javascript to build the list, but the principle is still the same with List from lisp or clojure or any language. Any answer using any kind of language is accepted.

> Write a function that adds the two numbers and returns the sum as a linked list. If the sum is greater than 10, extra one digit will be carried to the tail
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> Input: (3 -> 1 -> 5) + (5 -> 9 -> 2)
>   Output: 8 -> 0 -> 8

My List Class always start with one head, then followed with next, next, next and so on

```
List = function(){
  this.head = {
     value: null,
     next: null
  }
}
```

EXAMPLE of List:

```
var listA = new List();
/* sample data-structure
listA = {
  head:{
     value: 3,
     next:{
        value: 1,
        next: {
           value: 5,
           next: null
        }
     } 
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: This isn't a Clojure question.

Comment: List is main part of Lisp language (in fact Lisp === List processing). Clojure is dialect of Lisp. now tell me what do you mean by clojure questions?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the `clojure` language whatsoever. You are simply asking about a linked list. While its the primary data structure in lisps (including clojure) *most* programming languages have a list data type. Your code is in `javascript`, ergo it has *nothing* to do with clojure.

Comment: for ChrisForrence, thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proposal of a possible solution for different list length.

Contains

- Node object with the properties `value` and `next`.
- Function `setValues`, which creates a new list of nodes with the given array.
- Function `add` which takes two lists of nodes and returns a new list of nodes with the result of summing the values of the same level.

```js
function Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = undefined;
}

function setValues(a) {
    return a.reduceRight(function (r, v) {
        var o = new Node(v);
        if (r) {
            o.next = r;
        }
        return o;
    }, undefined);
}

function add(l1, l2) {
    var value = 0,
        last, list;

    while (l1 || l2) {
        if (l1) {
            value += l1.value;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        if (l2) {
            value += l2.value;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        if (last) {
            last.next = new Node(value % 10);
            last = last.next;
        } else {
            list = new Node(value % 10);
            last = list;
        }
        value = value / 10 | 0;
    }
    if (value) {
        last.next = new Node(value);
    }
    return list;
}

var list1 = setValues([3, 1, 5]),
    list2 = setValues([5, 9, 2]),
    list3 = add(list1, list2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Bonus: Version with recursive style.

```js
function Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = undefined;
}

function setValues(a) {
    var n = new Node(a.shift());
    if (a.length) {
        n.next = setValues(a);
    }
    return n;
}

function add(l1, l2, r) {

    function v(o, p) { return o && o[p] || 0; }

    r = (r || 0) + v(l1, 'value') + v(l2, 'value');
    var n = new Node(r % 10);
    l1 = v(l1, 'next');
    l2 = v(l2, 'next');
    r = r / 10 | 0;
    if (l1 || l2 || r) {
        n.next = add(l1, l2, r);
    }
    return n;
}

var list1 = setValues([3, 1, 5]),
    list2 = setValues([5, 9, 2]),
    list3 = add(list1, list2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```